# What should be the datatype for this type ("-07:00:00") of value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anybody help me?

What should be the datatype for this type `-07:00:00` of value in SQL Server 2008?

I have tried to search on the google but not get a proper answer.

Thanks

Comment: what type of value is this `"-07:00:00"`?? time??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

int

This looks like a presentation problem, rather than a true datetime problem. 
If so, I'd store this as -420 minutes or -25,200 seconds so it's more useful

Comment: @OlegDok: this would be +/- 9 hours in seconds. It depends on the range and resolution needed.

Answer (score 1):

- [N][var]char(9)
- in some circumstances - TIME (when somehow passed as *positive* value)